# Build not working in Release managment while succeeded in TFS with disable release trigger

Tags: tfsbuild, ms-release-management

I am trying to deploy a code using Release management but getting excpetion :

> exception Message: Release build failed (type Exception)
>       Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I edited build definition and disabled the Release trigger. Then build gets succeeded without triggering a release but If I start manual release from RM client with latest build that just created it fails with error message  :

[image]

Comment: Look at the log. Exit code 4 is from xcopy. `Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line.`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this question for troubleshooting: [What is going wrong when Visual Studio tells me "xcopy exited with code 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626557/what-is-going-wrong-when-visual-studio-tells-me-xcopy-exited-with-code-4)

> Xcopy exit code 4 means *"Initialization error occurred. There is not
>   enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or
>   invalid syntax on the command line."*
>
> It looks like Visual Studio is supplying invalid arguments to xcopy.
>   Check your post-build event command via Project Properties > Right
>   Click > Build Events > Post Build Event.
>
> Note that if the $(ProjectDir) or similar macro terms have spaces in
>   the resulting paths when expanded, then they will need to be wrapped
>   in double quotes.

And the error can also occur when the destination folder is read-only, please also check this in the deployed server.