# VS2012 Post Build XCopy Exclude Not Working?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xcopy, post-build-event

I have the following line in my post build events. I want to copy all files and folders except the file types in the excludedfileslist.txt (which current just has **.cs** in it) to my web project.

```
xcopy /r /d /i /s /y /exclude:$(SolutionDir)excludedfileslist.txt $(SolutionDir)MyForum.Logic\App_Plugins\ $(SolutionDir)MyForum.Web\App_Plugins\
```

But when I run it I get the following error

```
exited with code 4.
```

I have checked the file paths in the error list in VS2012 and the full file paths it creates are correct? So I'm stumped why this is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861474/command-copy-exited-with-code-4-when-building-visual-studio-restart-solves-it

Answer (score 0):

Ignore I have sorted it

```
xcopy /r /d /i /s /y /exclude:$(SolutionDir)excludedfileslist.txt "$(SolutionDir)MyForum\App_Plugins" "$(SolutionDir)MyForum\App_Plugins\"
```