# Visual Studio's post-build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event

I am trying to copy some files on post-build event. These directories are on the same local repository. 
I was successful to copy these files on the target path however I am having some issues when I build the proj under the target path. I get **code 4** error. I think what's causing the problem is that there are some files not accessible on the target path that was included on the post-build command. I am thinking of a possible solution but is still quite unsure how to perform that. Currently when I checked the post-build command on the target path, it does have a post-build command included. Is it possible to clear command on the target paths post-build event? Like make it as the default value.

I am using this code command for the post-build event:

```
xcopy $(SolutionDir)repo\Project\*.* $(SolutionDir)Artifacts\Project\src\ /y /s /exclude:$(SolutionDir)excludelist.txt
```

And when I try to build the project on the target path (Artifacts), I got this error:

```
Can't read file: C:(SolutionDir)\Artifacts\Project\src\excludelist.txt
```

I understand that excludelist.txt is not accessible since the directory included on the post-build command is on the original directory where the Artifacts folder was copied. So I am wondering if I can however make the post-build command of Artifacts empty by default.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE: (solved)**
[This solution works for me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861474/command-copy-exited-with-code-4-when-building-visual-studio-restart-solves-it) 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To help you get help please provide more details. "I am trying to copy some files on post-build event." :  Please show how. " I get code 4 error" : Normally there is additional error description, please share that.

Comment: See this previous post for possible help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861474/command-copy-exited-with-code-4-when-building-visual-studio-restart-solves-it

Comment: @JonP Hi, thanks for the advise :) I've edited it already. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Hi, I had already tried that solution. Sadly, it doesn't work for me though. Thanks btw

Comment: Did you see the answer posted by Vemul…. It there he states: Another possible issue is that the underlying folder cannot be accessed. If so, trying performing "start xcopy" instead of "xcopy". This will open another command window but with admin priveleges.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani that's great! the error doesn't occur after using "start xcopy" instead of just "xcopy". But is it possible to make the default post-build event of the copied Artifacts empty?